# Make sure range value doesn't overlap with existing ranges

Tags: mysql, php, validation

I have some range information stored in a database as min_age and max_age, for example:

```
id      min_age     max_age
1       10          14
2       15          16
3       17          20
```

I want to do some validation using PHP (or MySql) so that, before another record is created, we make sure that the range doesn't overlap with an existing range. So, id=4, min_age=21, max_age=25 would be fine, but id=4, min_age=20, max_age=25 would fail. My (psuedo)code, thusfar:

```
$age['min'] = $x;
$age['max'] = $y;
$current ranges = db_query('SELECT min_age, max_age FROM age_table')->fetchAll();
foreach ($age as $limit)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($current_ranges); $i++)
    {
        if ($limit >= $current_ranges[$i]->min_age && $limit <= $current_ranges[$i]->max_age) $conflict = $result[$i]->entity_id;
    }
}
    if ($conflict) fail();
```

But this is an oversimplification (isn't it?), as it just tests to see if the min/max values fall within the defined ranges. I think this *may* work but employs some fuzzy logic on my part... can anyone help sharpen me up on this? Cheers...

Comment: Better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: can you have a gap? can id=4 be 25-30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create an array with all the values in the [min,max] range, then do an intersect with all the existing ranges:

```
$new_range = range($min, $max);
foreach ($current_ranges as $range) {
  if (count(array_intersect($new_range, range($range["min"], $range["max"])))) {
    throw new RangeException();
  }
}
```

This will throw an exception on the first already-existing range coinciding with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

you simple use the following sql query to achieve this like

```
SELECT min_age, max_age FROM age_table WHERE min_age >= $min_age or max_age >= $max_age
```

if the range does not exists in your db than this query wil return nothing else it will return the filtered rows.