# Determine if a range overlaps existing ranges, then add the range if not

Tags: python, range, overlap

I need to implement an algorithm where the input is a range `(start, end)`, and I have to determine if the range overlaps with any existing ranges, e.g., `[(s1, e1), (s2, e2), ...]`. If yes, *optionally* return the overlapping range. If no, append the range to the list.

I've read [this question on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8451789/149900), unfortunately I'm not sure if this is suitable for my situation, because the `start` and `end` of each range might be in the **millions**. And no, I cannot reduce the magnitude; I need unit precision.

Searching around, I found [Mr. Ned Batchelder's trick](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201310/range_overlap_in_two_compares.html), and albeit quite optimized, I'm concerned of the performance effect if I have to do the comparison over **thousands of tuples**.

Now if push comes to shove, I think I'll just iterate the latter trick over the list, but I certainly wish there's a better way.

(Note: I don't *have* to store existing ranges in a list of tuples. If there's a better way, I can marshal the range tuple into the necessary structure. But the input *must* be `(start, end)`)

If you have a better way, care to share?

Comment: I assume that none of the existing ranges in the list overlap. Are they sorted?

Comment: No, the existing ranges do not overlap, for the list was dynamically created from non-overlapping ranges. Current implementation of the list is not sorted. But, as I wrote, I can force the list to be sorted if necessary for performance. Will that help?

Comment: Yes! Sorting will certainly help, as it will permit a simple [bisection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) search.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Hadn't thought of using bisection before. This calls for some deep thinking on my side... thanks for the tip!

Comment: The downside is that inserting the new range into the sorted list is expensive, especially if there are a lot of tuples already in the list. So if the list is big and insertion is slow (since it requires making a new list) it may be a better strategy to use some form of binary tree to store the tuples.

Comment: Have a look at [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). They do what you want in a more generalized way in an optimal time.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you! That's very educating... And there's even an [intervaltree package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree)! I won't ever find that without your helpful hint :-)

Comment: @Bakuriu can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

binary tree seems like a good match here

if you get something simple like

```
class node():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.less = None
        self.more = None
```

and then have some function to fit into a tree:

```
def fit(val, top_node):
    current_node = top_node
    while True:
        if val[0] < current_node.val[0] and val[1] < current_node.val[0]:
            if current_node.less:
                 current_node = current_node.less
                 continue
            else:
                 current_node.less = node(val)
                 break
        elif val[0] > current_node.val[1]:
            if current_node.more:
                current_node = current_node.more
                continue
            else:
                current_node.more = node(val)
                break
        print('not a fit!')
        break
```

now all is left is to refine if things go slow because the tree got too deep

Answer (score 1):

What do you want are [interval trees](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). They are a data structure that contain (overlapping) intervals and allow for efficient queries, insertions and deletions. In fact it's been proven that their time complexities for queries are optimal.

If you are handling only non overlapping ranges operations will simply be more efficient, but there's no drawback in using them, although they can handle the general case.

There is an [intervaltree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) package available to download.